# How to pass hash at end of vararg list?

Tags: ruby

I have a function that takes a vararg with an optional hash that can be passed as the last item:

```
def func(*args)
  options = args.last.is_a?(Hash) ? args.pop : {}
  items = args

end
```

How would I call this function, if I have an array and would like to also pass a hash?

```
x = [ "one", "two", "three" ]
....                              
func(*x, :on => "yes")            # doesn't work, i get SyntaxError
```

The SyntaxError message is:

```
syntax error, unexpected tSYMBEG, expecting tAMPER
fun(*x, :on => "yes")
```

I'm running ruby v1.8.7.

Answer (score 1):

Call it without the `*` before the first arg.

```
def func(*args)
  options = args.last.is_a?(Hash) ? args.pop : {}
  items = args

  puts "Options: On: #{options[:on]}, Off: #{options[:off]}\n" if options.length > 0
  p args
end

func(x, 123, 'a string', {:on => "yes", :off => "no"})

# Prints:
Options: On: yes, Off: no
[["one", "two", "three"], 123, "a string"]
```

Comment: `puts` recursively flattens an array passed to it, so this doesn’t really work as you might thing – the three args are still all in an array of there own. Try it with `p` instead of `puts`.

Comment: @matt Why shouldn't they still be an array? They were passed as an array, which is _a single argument_.  Output is confusing - I'll change the call to include additional non-array args and not use `puts`

Comment: In Ruby 1.9, you can use `*` to destructure an array. In the example in the question, `func(*x, :on => "yes")` (where `x` is a three element array) is the same as passing _four_ arguments to the method – like `func('one', 'two', 'three', {:on => "yes"})`. This doesn’t work in 1.8.7 though – you get the syntax error. So this answer is a way of getting it to work in 1.8.7, but it won’t be quite the same as what you can do in 1.9. Just something to be aware of.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Based on your example, the output I actually want is this: [ "one", "two", "three", 123, "a string" ] --The one-two-three array expanded and everything is one flat array.  On 1.8.7...